# Converting timezones using pytz on Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, pytz

I am trying to convert the timezone of a pandas Series. I am using the pytz package to do so, however I am getting a value that is off by a few minutes. 
The code I am currently using can be found in the answer here: [Converting Items from Pandas Series to Date Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062108/converting-items-from-pandas-series-to-date-time)

Other answers suggest using the `localize()` function to make this work, however this does not work in my code. I tried using the `normalize()` function to solve this issue but I am getting an error using a pandas series.

> Error message: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute
>   'tzinfo'

Sample input:

```
dfNY = pd.DataFrame({'TimeSeries': [13:00, nan, 06:00, 'Morning', 'Afternoon', nan, nan, 01:30]})
```

Desired output:

```
dfLondon = pd.DataFrame({'TimeSeries': [18:00, nan, 11:00, 'Morning', 'Afternoon', nan, nan, 06:30]})
```

Current code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pytz import timezone
    dfNY = pd.DataFrame({'TimeSeries': [13:00, nan, 06:00, 'Morning', 'Afternoon', nan, nan, 01:30]})
    tzDestination = "Europe/London"
    dtTimeSeries = pd.to_datetime(dfNY.TimeSeries, errors='coerce', format='%H:%M').dt.tz_localize(tzOrigin)
    tzChange = timezone(tzDestination)
    convertedTime = tzChange.normalize(dtTimeSeries).dt.strftime('%H:%M')
    dyNY = convertedTime.copy()
    dfNY = timeSeries.where(~convertedTime.ne('NaT'), convertedTime)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: could you show the code you are using too? Adding the error message without the code producing it is not really useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change utcoffset of a Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304394/change-utcoffset-of-a-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

When I run the code from [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062108/converting-items-from-pandas-series-to-date-time) it works just fine.  Compare your code to IMCoins' and see where the difference is (you create a separate time series whereas IMCoins keeps everything within the dataframe).

Second, regarding why the time stamp is off by four minutes, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41304707/1678467).  How can you fix this?  Well, I doubt you have data from the year 1900, so you could set the date as something AFTER 1-Jan. 1902.

Comment: If you look at the output of the previous answer - he is off by 5min as well. I find that on different machines, the output differs 

The issue with the answer you provided is that it does not work with pandas Series. I localize the data in the series dtTimeSeries

Comment: Sorry, I do not see any differences amongst the answers.  The offset is consistently off by 4 minutes.  As shown in the linked answer (second link) this offset is not wrong, it is due to how time was recorded in the early 20th century (why four minutes matters, I don't know...it's just the way its done, so no bug here).

Comment: 1. answer in other question does not solve the minutes issue
2. I am unable to get the desired result regardless of using the localize method
3. I still get an error with the pandas data-series if I try to use the "normalize" method